# How to check aws sqs queue is available before accessing it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sqs, localstack

Sorry, if I sound noob. But I am implementing localstack SQS using docker in my project and my server fails when the queue has not been created.

I did some research and found that we can add health check for other containers. But to add healthcheck.

I am not sure how I can check if the queue has successfully created?

After only healthcheck is successful it should start the main container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQS wasn't really designed for the use case of dynamic queues. One way is to test to see if the queue exists with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
until aws sqs get-queue-url --queue-name bob; do
  sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CLI to list available queues.
`aws sqs list-queues --queue-name-prefix My`

```
{
   "QueueUrls": [
        "https://testurl.com/example/MyDeadLetterQueue",
        "https://testurl.amazonaws.com/example/MyQueue",
        "https://testurl.amazonaws.com/example/MyOtherQueue"
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view local SQS for localstack using [Commandeer](https://getcommandeer.com) It also works for AWS SQS.

[image]